# Using "plus ... que je m'attendais"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, comparatifs

Can I say

> L'examen était plus difficile que je m'attendais

to mean "The exam was more difficult than I expected"?

Or do I need to put in *ce à quoi*?

> L'examen était plus difficile que **ce à quoi** je m'attendais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "... plus difficile **que ce à quoi je m'attendais**" is correct, I would much rather say:

> L'examen s'est avéré plus difficile **que je (ne) (me) l'imaginais**.
>
> L'examen s'est avéré plus difficile **que je (ne) le pensais**.
>
> L'examen s'est avéré plus difficile **que prévu**.

Answer (score -1):

L'examen était plus difficile que ce à quoi je m'attendais is the correct answer